# ARC: Heapshots shows growing heap, but no own classes

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

How can I track down abandoned memory if in Xcode Instruments don´t show my custom classes?

[image: Xcode Instruments]

So I can see the heap is growing after I perform an action with my app (open a view and go back to the previous in my case) and I could fix some memory issues before by tracking down my mistakes in my code.

Now however, I only see things like in `Generation N` (= Heapshot N), `non-object` and I don´t know any more how I can fix the leaks. The responsible caller (not seen in the screenshots) also show no own classes/objects.

### Edit

The Showing View is a `UIWebView`. I searched the web and found rumors that `UIWebView` doesnt properly releasing data. Could that be the issue? I can´t find any solution.

Comment: That row highlighted on your screen is probably some cached layer

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` is notorious for causing memory issues.

1. Make sure you set the `UIWebView` object's `delegate` property to nil if you assigned an object to it as documented in the class reference. You can do this in `dealloc`.
2. Cleanup the web view in `viewWillDisappear:animated:` by stopping URL loading with a call to `stopLoading` and/or setting the HTML string to nil by calling `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` to workaround any memory being held.

Comment: hi friend, thanks for your detailed answer. Sadly the symptoms still appear after the changes.